# Dynamic binding of table column and rows

Tags: sapui5

I'm having troubles getting dynamic binding of both my table columns and rows to work.

Suppose I have two models, one holding the table column info:

```
    var aColumnData = [
        {
            columnId : "col1"
        },
        {
            columnId : "col2"
        },
        {
            columnId : "col3"
        },
        {
            columnId : "col4"
        },
        {
            columnId : "col5"
        }
    ];
```

and one with the data:

```
var aData = [
    {
        col1 : "Row 1 col 1",
        col2 : "Row 1 col 2",
        col3 : "Row 1 col 3",
        col4 : "Row 1 col 4",
        col5 : "Row 1 col 5"
    },
    {
        col1 : "Row 2 col 1",
        col2 : "Row 2 col 2",
        col3 : "Row 2 col 3",
        col4 : "Row 2 col 4",
        col5 : "Row 2 col 5"
    }
];
```

I then set the model :

```
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData({
        columns : aColumnData,
        rows    : aData
    });
```

I then create my table in the view:

```
    var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table();

    var oColumnTemplate = new sap.ui.table.Column({
        label : "{columnDesc}",
        template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", "<this_should_be_dynamic_but_how?>")
    });

    oTable.bindColumns("/columns", oColumnTemplate);
    oTable.bindRows("/rows");
```

The part that bugs me is the binding to the current column in the TextView template; this should be dynamic ("col1", "col2", etc) and done on the fly -- that's what bindings are for anyway I assume -- but I can't get it to work...

I guess I'm missing something simple and trivial, but I'm a bit lost now...
Any help is highly appreciated!

==============================

*EDIT: I got it to work by iterating through the columns array and using the addColumn() method:*

```
    jQuery.each(aColumnData, function(i, v) {
        oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label : v.columnDesc, 
            template: new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindProperty("text", v.columnId) 
        })); 
    });
```

*...but I was hoping there would be a more cleaner approach using the bindColumns() / bindRows() approach:*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have done something similar before [using factory functions](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/BindingAggregations.html) see [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/qaqur/1/edit) for similar example to yours

```
var oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
    title: "Table column and data binding",
    showNoData : true,  
    columnHeaderHeight : 10,
    visibleRowCount: 7
});
oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindColumns("/columns", function(sId, oContext) {
    var sColumnId = oContext.getObject().columnId;
    return new sap.ui.table.Column({
        id : sColumnId,
        label: sColumnId, 
        template: sColumnId, 
        sortProperty: sColumnId, 
        filterProperty: sColumnId
    });
});
oTable.bindRows("/rows");
```

you could use 2 globally named models in this scenario, one for the metadata one for the data
eg

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oMetaModel, 'meta');
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oDataModel, 'data');
..
oTable.bindColumns("meta>/columns" function...
oTable.bindRows("data>/rows");
```

Heres an example [jsbin example of dynamic columns based on OData metadata](http://jsbin.com/howip/1/edit)

Comment: Excellent @Jasper_07 , works like a charm! You're a true life **and** timesaver! :-)

Comment: is it also possible to modify one single row from a textview template and all others from a link template?

Comment: @zyrex yes, you can after binding the template and data, insert an item at index 0 using oTable.insertRow(oRow, iIndex)

Comment: @Jasper_07 Is there a way to bind rows that are in arrays of array format instead of array of objects. Also, the arrays have no mapping columns as such. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793535/how-to-map-model-to-table-when-the-structure-is-array-based

Comment: Does this code work if I am using XML view with predefined table that needs additional column?