# How to map model to table when the structure is array based?

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, sapui5

I have my data as following:

```
{
    meta: {
              format: "csv",
              info: "desc",
              columns: [
              {
                  id: "Name",
                  type: "Text",
                  length: 32          
              }, 
              {
                  id: "Text",
                  type: "Text",
                  length: 128
              }]
          },
    rows: [
              ["John","xxxx"],
              ["Alpha","yyyy"],
              ["Beta","wwww"],
              ["Gamma","zzzz"]]
}
```

Now, I am struggling to map the records to a `Table` control as `Columns` and `Rows`. Column seems straight forward, straight map, but the rows since lacks a mapping to column I wonder what could be the simplest way.

Approach Steps:

1. Make a `keys[]` from `column.id` of each columns record.
2. Traverse the `rows[]`
3. Each loop, while `keys.length` create an object as `{keys[j]:row[k]}`
4. Push to an array
5. Recreate the original `JSON` but replace `Rows` arrays with `Objects`

I am really struggling to translate this into code specially at the `rows[]` parsing and creating Objects. Is there, I am sure there must be, an efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you could do. using Array.map and forEach.

```js
var input = {
  meta: {
    format: "csv",
    info: "desc",
    columns: [{
      id: "Name",
      type: "Text",
      length: 32
    }, {
      id: "Text",
      type: "Text",
      length: 128
    }]
  },
  rows: [
    ["John", "xxxx"],
    ["Alpha", "yyyy"],
    ["Beta", "wwww"],
    ["Gamma", "zzzz"]
  ]
};


var columns = input.meta.columns.map((column) => {
  return column.id
});


var rows = input.rows.map((row) => {
  var obj = {};
  row.forEach((column, idx) => {
    obj[columns[idx]] = column;
  });
  return obj;
});

input.rows = rows;
console.log(input);
```

Comment: many thanks for the reply. This solution works absolutely bang on to get the desired result. Although, my question was a little more towards  wondering if there is any smart way of doing the same in SAPUI5 data binding for Table without the need of pre-processing the data. But if thats not possible I'll mark this as the right answer.

Comment: I m no expert on sapui5 at all. I wont be able to answer, if there is a better way to do it in SAPUI.  However, in general, you need to have a transformer in place to convert from one structure to another. It could either be at server / client.