# Mapping array of arrays to sap.m.Table control

Tags: javascript, arrays, sapui5

I have my data as following:

```
{
    meta: {
              format: "csv",
              info: "desc",
              columns: [
              {
                  id: "Name",
                  type: "Text",
                  length: 32          
              }, 
              {
                  id: "Text",
                  type: "Text",
                  length: 128
              }]
          },
    rows: [
              ["John","xxxx"],
              ["Alpha","yyyy"],
              ["Beta","wwww"],
              ["Gamma","zzzz"]]
}
```

Now, I am struggling to map the records to a `sap.m.Table` control as `Columns` and `Rows`. Column seems straight forward, straight map, but the rows are array of arrays structure. Is there a way to bind this structure which is not an array of objects?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793535/how-to-map-model-to-table-when-the-structure-is-array-based. What is the problem? Is the solution provided not sufficient?

Comment: @matbtt Its not exactly a duplicate. Instead of editing the question, which has a perfect answer already, I thought of clarifying my problem exactly, as I did it in the comment of that question. This one is more of a **SAPUI5/OPENUI5** oriented problem than a JS solution.

Comment: If you got a perfect answer you should accept it. Then anybody can see that and the answerer earns reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it is possible to create a property binding if you use the array index instead of a property name.

```
<List id="list" items="{/rows}>
   <columns>
       <Column>
           <Label text="{/meta/columns/0/id}"/>
       </Column>
       <Column>
           <Label text="{/meta/columns/1/id}"/>
       </Column>
   </columns>
   <items>
       <ColumnListItem>
           <cells>
               <Text text="{0}"/>
               <Text text="{1}"/>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>   
   </items>
</List>
```

Dynamically you can do the binding as follows in the controller. It should be easy to adapt to your use case:

```
var list = this.byId("list");

list.bindAggregation("columns", {
    "path" : "/meta/columns",
    "template" : new sap.m.Column({ 
        "header" : new sap.m.Label({ 
            "text" : "{name}" 
        })
    })
});

list.bindAggregation("items", {
    "path" : "/rows",
    "template" : new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        "cells" : [
            new sap.m.Text({ "text" : "{0}" }), 
            new sap.m.Text({ "text" : "{1}" })
        ]})
});
```

The list must not contain any binding information.

```
<List id="list"/>
```

If you need more control over the binding process you can use factory functions instead of templates.

```
list.bindAggregation("columns", {
    "path" : "/meta/columns",
    "factory" : function(id, context) {
        return new sap.m.Column({ 
            "header" : new sap.m.Label({ 
                "text" : "{name}" 
            })
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the issue I am not able to get around here is number of columns will be dynamic. Is there a way to dynamically bind the columns as well?

Comment: Not in a declaritive way. If you want that you need to code that.

Comment: Exactly. I am not getting any ideas to bind columns dynamically and then reference the same in rows. I see elsewhere people mention _formatter_ but I am new to this UI5 framework and not much resources to follow either. I was able to achieve similar results in ui.Table by using the solution in my 1st question but m.Table is completely different I see.

Comment: Many thanks. Highly appreciate your help. You are a life saver. By the time I saw your edit I had already written the column binding. See I'm learning fast :). One small thing though - the cells needs to be dynamic per number of columns, shouldn't they? Can I keep a count of columns we are creating to be able to loop somehow.

Comment: You can pass a factory function instead of template. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks again. I figured that out sometime back, the need of a factory method. For some reason the data doesn't show up in the table. I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AbhieSpeaks/3da2yrbx/ . If you don't mind just having a look if I missed anything.

Comment: You need to assemble the cells array inside the factory before you pass it to the ColumnList constructor:  return new sap.m.ColumnListItem({"cells" : cells}). Furthermore the property binding must be as follows: "text": "{" + i + "}"

Comment: Got it working. Its strange that I had to remove the _/metadata/_ path for column binding and only use _/columns_. Marked your solution as answer. Many many thanks. EDIT: Such a silly mistake. I already considered the meta/columns while creating the model /column. Learned a lot today.