# How to populate sapui5 smart table with data from a CSV file after importing?

Tags: sapui5

I am new to SAPUI5 and so am struggling to use `sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable` of sapUI5. I saw various examples but all of them make use of `oData` service which I don't need to use in my case.

Basically what I need to do is, import CSV file and show its data in `smartTable`. I am successful in showing the data in a simple table in SAP but unable to figure out how to use `smarttable` without any `oData` service in SAPUI5.

I am using XML view for view part.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not. It is not possible. As mentioned [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable.html) in documentation,

> The SmartTable control creates a table based on OData metadata and the configuration specified. The **entitySet** attribute must be specified to use the control

Comment: Do you know how to bind columns to xml view dynamically? Please share the code.

Comment: You can check at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731176/dynamic-binding-of-table-column-and-rows

Comment: I asked for smarttable and the link you posted doesn't use smarttable